# Create table with mapped object Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

So I have created an object and I'm using the Cassandra mapping, I was wondering though if it was possible to use the Mapper to create or update the table structure when it doesn't exist. The reason I say that is the object that will be in the table is constantly getting changed, it has new things added and occasionally it will also have fields removed. Due to this, we'd need to keep changing the table as well as the object and know exactly what data type to be using. It would be easier to just do this with the mapper itself or some other thing in the Cassandra driver.

An example object would look like

```
@Table(keyspace = "example", name = "example_data")
public class DataClass {

    private String identifier;
    private int someIntValue;
    private boolean someBooleanValue;
}
```

Now we may add to this the next version with something like

```
@Table(keyspace = "example", name = "example_data")
public class DataClass {

    private String identifier;
    private int someIntValue;
    private boolean someBooleanValue;
    private AnotherClass configuration;
}
```

Since this is a UDT it would be much easier to have this be generated with the mapper and modify the table with this.
If anyone has an idea on how to make the query or a way to like get the object so it can be used in a Cassandra query to create/modify the table that would be great. Please say if you need more details!